# Should I put Azure WorkerRole base.OnStop();

Tags: c#, azure, lifecycle, azure-worker-roles

The article guides Azure WorkerRole `OnStop` handling; https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/the-right-way-to-handle-azure-onstop-events/

In above link, it does not call `base.OnStop();` at the last line. But other code examples [[1]](https://blog.geist.no/using-autofac-dependency-injection-with-azure-worker-role/), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353434/why-is-stopping-onstop-not-called-when-scaling-in-in-azure), [[3]](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/64028bba-865d-4a58-bd8b-7bd870d92dce/onstop-vs-dispose-method-in-worker-role?forum=windowsazuredevelopment) have `base` call at the very last line.

Should I have to put this code?

Comment: It's not in the documentation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleentrypoint.onstop.aspx) either. Did you try it and did it work?

Comment: @MarkC. // I didn't try without `base` statement yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base class is abstract

```
public abstract class RoleEntryPoint
```

and the OnStop method is a virtual member

```
public virtual void OnStop()
```

I think the OnStop member does nothing, in the same way that the virtual method OnStop have no body definition in the ServiceBase class used to create Windows Services

[Why call base.OnStop() when Windows Service is stopped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620170/why-call-base-onstop-when-windows-service-is-stopped)

Also to mention that if they create that member as abstract they will force you to implement it in the derived class, even if you have nothing to include there.

So my 2 cent's will be that is not necessary to call base.OnStop(), just if you want to add extra code for the OnStop event.